# Multiple links with delay

Tags: html, hyperlink, tabs, web

I was wondering how to make a link, that when clicked it would open 2
links: One would open in a new tab instantly Second one would open in
a new window after a minute or so.

I also want to embed this in a website like weebly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an edit to make things simpler -

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('www.flvs.net');return true;">linky</a>
```

two opens one click

Comment: it opened a the 1st link but not the second.

Comment: my bad - just use single quotes then for the 2nd link

Comment: what does that &quot mean
is that another way to use a '

Comment: its another way of using double quote

Comment: ok well it didn't do anything 

when I clicked on the link it just opened the first link

can you try posting the code again but put a link to google or something where the site links are supposed to go.

Comment: try the edit now... but this results in a popup which google chrome and perhaps other browsers blocks i agree with user101 this is spammy

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very spammy and not recommended but if you were to do it, I would do it a separate  function rather than in line in the onclick html attribute.

Try the below. It will give a 5 second time gap between links.

```
function openPage1() {
    window.open(url1);
    window.setTimeout(openPage2,5000);
}

function openPage2() {
    window.open(url2);
}
```

// Just call openPage1 from your button click handler

```
openPage1();
```

Comment: so how would i new that so that the second link is delayed
I am kind of new to coding